# 1d arrays and 2d arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Im wondering how I could split a 1d array into a 2d array in java? 
I know how to set up both of them and i know that I have to iterate over both of them using for loops im just not sure how I would go about it. 
I have an array of students names and i want the first 5 to go on the top line and then the next 5 on the bottom line of the 2d array so as to create groups of 5 students.

so far I have:

```
public void main(String[] args)

{

  for (int x=0; x<5;x++)
  {
      for (int y=0; y<5;y++)
      {
          board[x][y] = (letters)y;
          System.out.print(board[x][y]);
          System.out.print("");
      }
  }
 }
```

How to I tell the it that i want this to be connected to the arrays

Comment: You are only using 1 array tho and that is the 2D one.

Comment: So do you mean you have 10 names only?

Comment: A 2D-array does not mean that is an array with two rows, it means it is an array which stores references to a 1D-arrays. A 3D-array stores references to 2D-arrays and so on...

Comment: +1. Thats what I was about to point to, because I think OP misunderstood the 2D array. What I think is OP wants the first iteration to stop at 2, but cannot be sure without his response.

Comment: People are just giving code as answers. I hope they would explain so whoever asks a question can understand what is going on and learn from it.

Comment: I don't understand the cast to letters in your code, but assume this is working.  
If I read what you want, it sounds like System.out.println() rather than System.out.print("") will give you the output you want.  
Nothing to do with 1 or 2 d arrays though.

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like your only problem is the calculation of the `letters` index. Try this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        board[x][y] = letters[x * 5 + y];
        System.out.print(board[x][y]);
        System.out.print("");
    }
}
```

This will create 2 "rows" of 5 students each.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at this code, it's also computing the indexes even if your 1D array has a number of elements which is not divisible by 5.

```
String[] names = new String[104];
double size = names.length;

String[][] yetAnother = new String[(int) Math.ceil(size / 5)][5];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    yetAnother[(int) Math.ceil(i / 5)][i % 5] = names[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the 2d array 5x(number of students / 5) or number of people per group by number of student / people per group /* number of groups */ so it is more dynamic.

You will only need one loop to achieve this. The loop goes through each of the names in the 1d array, get the names one by one and assign it to and appropriate index in the 2d array.

To figure out the index one of them could be just the counter of the loop mod(%) people per group this will keep the index between 0 to 4. To figure out the other index you could mod(%) the loop counter with (number of student / people per group)

so it will look like `board[i%ppg][i%nog]` ppg being people per group and nog being number of groups. You can easily calculate number of groups.

EDIT: 2d arrays are easy if you have a really simple way to visualize them. The trick I did when I was learning 2d arrays was to think of them as chess boards. Chess boards got vertical and horizontal indices represented by letters and number just like 2d arrays except in programming it is just numbers.